# .net web based application with Web page hosted with IIS

Tags: iis

We have a web based application with Web page hosted with IIS. Server has dual NIC card (I mean with two IP address IP1 and IP2).

One NIC card connected to Network 1 (IP1) – plant network connecting server and operator stations

Second NIC card connected to Network 2 (IP2) – kind of a lab network.

The question is:

1. Is it possible to bind Web pages with IP2? So that only clients connected to lab network can access these pages?
2. Also we need to see, whether its possible to bind both the IPs so that plant network also get access to this web pages?

We tried point 1, but we were not successful.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

IIS can restrict access based on a client IP range. Restrictions can be applied to specific pages, sites, folders, and/or applications.

See documentation on TechNet for instructions on setting up IP restrictions on [IIS7 (and later)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770819%28WS.10%29.aspx) or for [IIS6](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731042.aspx).